Read Parquet files from an Amazon S3 bucket into R using the sparklyr package
I am attempting to read Parquet files from an Amazon S3 bucket into R using the sparklyr package. My approach involves configuring Spark to interface with S3 by specifying the necessary Hadoop AWS package and setting AWS credentials.
**1. Setting AWS Credentials:
**
I have set my AWS credentials in the R environment using:

r
Copy code
Sys.setenv(
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "YOUR_ACCESS_KEY",
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "YOUR_SECRET_KEY",
  AWS_DEFAULT_REGION = "YOUR_REGION"
)


**2. Configuring Spark:
**
I have created a Spark configuration to include the hadoop-aws package and specified the S3A filesystem implementation:

r
Copy code
config <- spark_config()
config$spark.jars.packages <- "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.2.0"
config$spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl <- "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem"
config$spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key <- Sys.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
config$spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key <- Sys.getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")



**3. Establishing Spark Connection:
**
I have initiated a Spark connection with the specified configuration:

r
Copy code
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", config = config)


**4. Reading Data from S3:
**
I have attempting to read Parquet files from the S3 bucket:

r
Copy code
vehicle_data <- spark_read_parquet(sc, 
                                   name = "vehicle_data", 
                                   path = "s3a://road-safety-data/filtered_parquet/vehicle_data/")


